# string addition associativity in cpp

Tags: c++

`string result;
result += argv[0] + " "; //Case1: throws error: invalid operands
result = result + argv[0] + " "; //Case2: works fine`

Looks like above addition statements are not equal.
I think in Case1,  argc[0] + " " is treated as (argv[0] + " ") is my understanding right?
Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: `//Case1: throws error: invalid operands` -- Is that the entire error message that the compiler is giving you?

Comment: No. Exact error is "invalid operands of types 'char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary operator+

Comment: ok, you do see that the part of the error message you left out is the answer to your question.

Comment: ya. I was under impression that result += argv[0] + " " will be treated as result = result + argv[0] + " " by the compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `+` is left-to-right associative, so let's start from the assumption that `a + b + c` is `(a + b) + c`. You can ignore `=` and `+=` operators in your example because they come later into play.

The problem here arises from the fact that `argv[0]` is a `char*`, not a `std::string`, so to allow `argv[0] + " "` you'd need a free `operator+(const char*, const char*)` which doesn't exist.

On the other hand `std::string` has

```
string::string& operator+(const char* s) const;
```

so your second scenario works because it starts with a `std::string` and produces `std::string` results.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. This is why case 1 fails because you can't apply `operator+` to `const char[]` and `const char[]`.